# Can i boot a linux kernel without passing a separate DTB from bootloader?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot

Trying to upgrade an IMX board to latest kernel but was looking at the ways to do it with the Legacy boot.  The version of the bootloader does  not include support for a separate DTB to be passed.

Comment: is it arm ? if yes it depends upon the version of the kernel, 3.x and below don't need dtb, just `fastboot boot -c 'console=tty1' zImage`

Comment: Yes, its ARM and I am looking to upgrade to Kernel 4.x

Comment: Then your kernel likely needs to be given a dtb as well.  Is the problem that your bootloader version doesn't support passing the address?

Comment: Yes, the bootloader is too old and I am trying to look for ways that I can upgrade the kernel without upgrading the bootloader.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is in the kernel the `ARM_APPENDED_DTB` config option.  This will let you include the DTB to use with the platform in the same file as the kernel.  This can then be booted the normal way on your platform and the kernel will look and find the included DTB.